# Entity Framework Script Generation

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

How can I get the sql query generated by the Context.SaveChanges(); command. I need this because, the user will have the option to create a script for data distribution, instead of inserting in the local base.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I'm using entity framework with WCF Data Services.

Comment: If it's a single or small number of queries, you can see (and copy) the exact queries being run in SQL Server Profiler (www.codeproject.com/Articles/21371/SQL-Server-Profiler-Step-by-Step). If you mean generate the script on the fly, then I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm working with entity framework, the generated sql is very complex to maintain I believe.

Comment: Could you not provide them with a very simple bit of software that takes in the data (maybe in CSV or however they want) and uses the standard interface. I wouldn't want people running Complex SQL scripts directly on the DB.

Comment: For now I'm just using the UI data to generate the scripts, its how you said, the query generated by entity is very complex, almost impossible to maintain. I really need better unknowledge for data distribution in sql servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is: Do not use Wcf Data Services which is still incomplete, if you need security and reliability, use Wcf Services, so you can have entity framework in its own extent. Wcf data services is not mature enough.

For the scripts, iam using string concatenation with stringbuilder.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using EF6, you can use `DbContext.Database.Log`. For instance, using the following, the SQL will be outputted to the console along some performance data:

```
Context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
```

You may also perform interception in case you want to stop `DbContext.SaveChanges` from actually saving the changes.

You can find information about both logging and interception in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn469464).

In case you are using previous versions, may check out either [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx) or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx) article.

Comment: This could be done, but I'm using WCF Data Services, which is very limited. For now, I'm creating the sql scripts with stringbuilder... yeah, not the best solution.

Comment: And by the way, the queries generated are very complex, and almost impossible to maintain.